# Is torsion of a topological module closed?

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I was asking to myself the following question. Consider a $p$-adically complete and separated topological algebra $R$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. As $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a domain, we know that the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-torsion elements of $R$ form a submodule. Is it possible to prove that this torsion is a closed submodule of $R$? I'm interested in the possibility of saying that the quotient of $R$ over its torsion is again $p$-adically complete, but in order to do this, I think I need that the torsion submodule is closed. Have you got any idea? I tried to prove it by hands but I didn't reach anything useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much, I just corrected everything!

Comment: [Crossposted at mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234790/is-torsion-submodule-of-a-p-adically-complete-and-separated-mathbbz-p-m/234796#234796). I posted an answer there.